# EnableOptimizations = true not minifying js only bundling

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

to bundle and minify js code i have added
following code

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations =true;
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app")
                 .Include("~/app/app.js")
                 .IncludeDirectory("~/app/Auth/", "*.js", searchSubdirectories: true)
                 .IncludeDirectory("~/app/Common/", "*.js", searchSubdirectories: true)
                   );

    }
```

and i have `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>`
in by web config.

**But its only bundling the files not minifying..**

can anyone tell where am wrong...?

Comment: .min.js files are already minified.

Comment: Except for the `app.js` file, you are already including `.min` versions (which is not normal practice anyway - one of the reasons for bundles is to include non-minified versions which are used in debug, but will be automatically minified in release mode)

Comment: @StephenMuecke please look on my updated code..some of my files are minified and some are not..

Answer (score 1):

The bundle doesn’t work in the debug mode. Thus, we set the debug value false in web.config file, as shown in the snippet, given below:

```
<system.web>  
   <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.1" />  
</system.web>
```

for more information https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-performance-bundling-and-minification/

Comment: you can try only <compilation debug="false" />

Answer (score 0):

To enable bundling and minification **debug** key in web.config should bet set to **false** value:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5"/>
```